# Python: How to use random to get two numbers in different orders

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a fast way to get 2 integers randomly say 1, 2 or 2, 1.

```
    var1 = random.randint( 1, 2 )
    # do something
    var2 = random.???       # say if var1 == 1, var2 should be 2.
    # do something else
```

Is there something that can be done to achieve following (*Some other syntactical way*)

```
    var2 = ( 1, 2 ) - var1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many solutions are possible, but the one which matches your idea most would be to use a compact if else statement:

```
import random

var1 = random.randint(1, 2)
var2 = 2 if var1 == 1 else 1
```

Another easy way to go is to create a list of values and shuffle them:

```
import random

l = list(range(1, 3))
random.shuffle(l)
var1 = l[0]
var2 = l[1]
```

Or use an in build function of random directly sovling your issue:

```
import random

var1, var2 = random.sample([1, 2], k=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're looking for [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population
> sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.

```
import random
first, second = random.sample([1, 2], k=2)
print(first, second)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you should mix the inputs, you could use

```
a, b = random.sample([1, 2], k=2) # Where k would be count of elements
```

If you ok that there could be 2 same outputs

```
a, b = random.choices([1, 2], k=2)  # a == b possible
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked for *"a fast way"*, so here's one 10+ times faster than the other solutions:

```
from random import random

var1 = 1 if getrandbits(1) else 2
var2 = 2 if var1 == 1 else 1
```

Benchmark results including two even faster but longer ways:

```
  62 ns ± 0 ns  if getrandbits(1):
                    var1 = 1
                    var2 = 2
                else:
                    var1 = 2
                    var2 = 1

  65 ns ± 0 ns  if getrandbits(1):
                    var1, var2 = 1, 2
                else:
                    var1, var2 = 2, 1

  82 ns ± 0 ns  var1 = 1 if getrandbits(1) else 2
                var2 = 2 if var1 == 1 else 1

  88 ns ± 2 ns  var1 = 1 if random_() < 0.5 else 2
                var2 = 2 if var1 == 1 else 1

 841 ns ± 3 ns  var1 = randint(1, 2)
                var2 = 2 if var1 == 1 else 1

 868 ns ± 4 ns  var1 = random.randint(1, 2)
                var2 = 1 + 2 - var1

 875 ns ± 2 ns  var1 = random.randint(1, 2)
                var2 = 2 if var1 == 1 else 1

1430 ns ± 4 ns  l = list(range(1, 3))
                random.shuffle(l)
                var1 = l[0]
                var2 = l[1]

2400 ns ± 4 ns  var1, var2 = random.sample([1, 2], k=2)
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVNtbtswDP2vU/BPYKn1vMhdii1YTuIahRvLrVBbESSlQDHsULvCLpaRkpy53QfiHzYt8j0@UqR9DU8Hc/PZutNpcIcJgp6UDqAne3ABnLKqCyx6fOiC9kHv/eydVK87U6KnVy8pyHWmx08O8E/HYRgVY16Fo4UdFEXBZuoY@TcU/WkTkLeb7KjK2d35bN2X8KgC2Q86eEak@0OvfE7w0jmJZoqtMhuXJdSCfDX6atADpLgdSFCjVyDZEnkpZETXiG3hCHpUBLkRguXcuX4@ipl6bNbtzDg2sk05S8hHMy4WzhsS0JbwvEMZM4MkHbkPXMBXWFebpKa@rLpIsOgfl@Iy/B@wLQN8Ztr5JzIwAr3x10v//9nO7aD63zGdfXX57sb@ddcSrrGiDxFNs1L54LTlovJ21IEXd@bOFNhfmnwaoW/7LTQtDAcHe9AG4mh9Z70a4gp4TgdZbSBAE@AKpPoSIYEgHsdY9TwyNhTeima7aduIcbgLzkCx@tSD8fDzB6xktApYAU87xYMXea/IRHXmOD0oR@Ws8WGU6p5SpbHbrKOgqBnTnWVnlQibtOFpm6N@JKeVLCHx7tJHCPiYTxLwdwFVZ60yWJNgyyy50pgMB1W97mKPohrr6C4WPSsjrEIZY7dX1PmiBHpfF1BcyVusc0aJ0@kX)):

```
from timeit import repeat
from statistics import median, stdev
from random import shuffle

setup = '''
import random
from random import randint, sample, random as random_, getrandbits
'''
codes = '''
var1 = random.randint(1, 2)
var2 = 2 if var1 == 1 else 1

var1 = randint(1, 2)
var2 = 2 if var1 == 1 else 1

l = list(range(1, 3))
random.shuffle(l)
var1 = l[0]
var2 = l[1]

var1, var2 = random.sample([1, 2], k=2)

var1 = 1 if random_() < 0.5 else 2
var2 = 2 if var1 == 1 else 1

var1 = 1 if getrandbits(1) else 2
var2 = 2 if var1 == 1 else 1

if getrandbits(1):
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 2
else:
    var1 = 2
    var2 = 1

if getrandbits(1):
    var1, var2 = 1, 2
else:
    var1, var2 = 2, 1

var1 = random.randint(1, 2)
var2 = 1 + 2 - var1
'''.strip().split('\n\n')

times = {c: [] for c in codes}
def stats(code):
    ts = [t * 1e9 for t in sorted(times[code])[:5]]
    return '%4d ns ± %1d ns ' % (median(ts), stdev(ts))

number = 10000
for _ in range(50):
  for code in codes:
    t = min(repeat(code, setup, number=number)) / number
    times[code].append(t)
for code in sorted(codes, key=stats):
  print(stats(code), code.replace('\n', '\n'+' '*16))
  print()
```

Comment: Wow that's really faster than others. Thanks for providing the benchmarking code as well.
For now I'm proceeding with solution provided by @Fruchtzwerg
`var1 = random.randint(1, 2)`
`var2 = 2 if var1 == 1 else 1`

Comment: Good to see the updated solutions, again saved ~20ns by eliminating condition checking twice

Comment: @joshi.mohit86 `random.random` has a much simpler implementation, that's why it's so much faster. All the other random functions are rather high-level, doing much more work (and might even partially be implemented in Python code rather than C code).

Comment: @joshi.mohit86 Turns out `getrandbits(1)` is even faster. (I checked the C code and saw that `random` and `getrandbits` seem to be the only two functions implemented in C).

Answer (score 0):

One approach specific to two integers that would match your original idea closely would be to subtract the chosen first integer from the sum of the two integers:

```
var1 = random.randint(1, 2)
var2 = 1 + 2 - var1
```